# UnsatisfiedLinkError when starting tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to enable PKI/CAC authentication in IBM Jazz Team Server.  I added the following line in the java.security file:

```
security.provider.1=com.ibm.security.capi.IBMCAC  <----- I added this line
security.provider.2=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.3=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.6=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.7=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.8=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.9=org.apache.harmony.security.provider.PolicyProvider
security.provider.10=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
```

The script works fine when I take out the IBMCAC entry from the server.xml file.

I get the following error when I try to start tomcat:

PS C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server> .\server.startup.bat

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ibmcac (Not found in java.library.path)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1035)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:999)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:507)
        at com.ibm.security.capi.IBMCAC$1.run(IBMCAC.java:58)
...
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
PS C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server>
```

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV74802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM cannot find the `ibmcac.dll` file.

Check the path environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the case, so I added the following to the catalina.bat file:               :noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\IBM\JazzTeamServer\server\jre\bin\ibmcac.dll"         I'm sure this is not correct....can you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: The `java.library.path` must point to a directory, not a file.

Comment: That fixed the ibmcac error, but it spawned a new error.  thanks for your help.  I'll try to figure out this new error myself before I ask.   Thanks for your help.